# How to contain card carousel inside viewport?

Tags: javascript, css

I was working with this card carousel. All the cards should be displayed in the viewport with the active card highlighted.

[image]

On clicking cards, right to active card, it works well but clicking left cards the cards are getting out of viewport and is overflowing.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/q0fLh6xc/)

Comment: did you try using https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: So what you want is to stop the cards from moving around?

Comment: It seems like you got more problems than that. If you click on the far right `.my-card` and then continue to click on the sibling left to the active card, the whole menu will scroll extremely far out to the right. I suggest that you rethink the entire code.

Comment: @Rickard Yes that's the issue. Any workarounds that, keeping the active card at center? Or any useful existing as such implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove animation code from js.

This one

```
if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
 $('.card-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '-=' + $slide});
} else if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
 $('.card-carousel').stop(false, true).animate({left: '+=' + $slide});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the overflowed content would solve this issue.  I will add it to the body since the body is the outer container of the carousel.

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```